# Apply separate formulas to separate columns but for the same row in Multi Index Dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

I'm working with a multi index dataframe and I am trying to apply two different formulas and append the calculation as a new row in the bottom ("Total").

However, because I am working with multi index dataframe, the calculation would differ depending on which sub-header it is.

**Dataframe:**

```
data = {'ID1': [1.0, 2.0,1.2,1.7,0.8,0.9], 'ID2': [5.0,3.0,7.0,2.0,1.0,6.0], 'Date': ['10-31-2022','12-31-2022','10-31-2022','12-31-2022','10-31-2022','12-31-2022'], 'Name': ['John', 'John', 'Kat', 'Kat', 'Adam','Adam']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame (data= data)
```

**Creating multi index:**

```
df1 = df1.set_index(["Date", "Name"])
df1 = df1.unstack().swaplevel(0,1, axis = 1).sort_index(axis = 1, level = 0, sort_remaining = False)
```

**df:**

[image]

In the "Total" row, I am trying to apply the cumprod function to the ID1 columns, and ID2 columns will simply be the mean.

I am able to calculate the columns by filtering to ID1 or ID2 only, however I would need to create separate rows for them.

**My output:**

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

Note: the numbers in the total row are random, just putting it there for visual reference.

**Calculation for ID1 columns:**

```
df_cumprod = (1 + df.filter(like='ID1')).cumprod(skipna = True) - 1

df_cumprod2 = df_cumprod.tail(1)

df_cumprod2.rename({df_cumprod2.index[-1]: 'Total'}, inplace = True)

df.append(df_cumprod2)
```

**Calculation for ID2 columns:**

```
df.loc['Total'] = df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='ID2'].mean()
```

This creates two "Total" rows, is there a way to merge them together so that they appear side by side in the same row (as shown in the expected output above)? Or apply two different formulas based on the condition of the column name to the same row?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've provided the code sample for the dataframe and the multi index.